# Quick questions (ExtJS, Sencha, ...)

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, extjs4

NOTE : To begin I'm sorry for my english. ;)

I plan working on a project that will be tested on android tablets (for the moment). I'm really interested by doing a webapp instead of a full-native application... Because I'm pretty sure that in a near future I'll have to deploy this app on non-tablet or non-android devices...

However I'm not familiar with ExtJS &co. So I don't know if all my goals could be achieved :

- 1 : I have to get informations from a Web Service (XML). And store files on a sdcard to read and write stuff using these informations. Is it possible, or not ?
- 2 : I want an offline mode. So I'll have to store datas as said before, and then check for a network connectivity when it exists and send these datas to a server.
- 3 : The main layout will be a list of clients, on the left, and a google map on the right with all clients displayed on it. Is the google map manipulation easy and complete using ExtJS ?

I think I'll use Sencha and Phonegap for the UI part. Any particular advice or recommendation?

Voilà. Thats enough for the moment I think. Thank you guys.

fr/Ron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 you can put your xml file within the application and deploy it by phonegap

2 I know you can do that, but there is a lot of way to do, depends on how you design this app

3 you can use google map api to plug in...it's very easy..... just type google map api in google then there is a google officially document and tutorial.

best regard,

Comment: For the first question, I really have to get the xml from webservice I can't deploy it within the application. I can do it using ExtJS?

Comment: you can do it with Ajax to call it.